# google play Admob ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

I created a game with Admob ads, but when I uploaded it to google play, google refuse it, they sent me this email

> Hi Developers at brsolab,
>
> I reviewed Move Up, com.brsolab.MoveUp, and noticed some policy issues
>   that need to be corrected. If you submitted an update, the previous
>   version of your app is still live on Google Play.
>
> Policy Issue: Your app was rejected for violating the ads policy. Your
>   app's advertisements are inappropriate for the intended audience of
>   your app.
>
> These guidelines apply to all content in your app, including user
>   generated content, in-app products, and advertisements. Here’s how you
>   can submit your app for another review:
>
> Check with your ad service provider to make sure the advertising
>   campaigns you selected will only show content consistent with your
>   app’s target audience. Sign in to your Developer Console and take the
>   content rating questionnaire again. Review your app to make sure it’s
>   in compliance with the policies listed in the Developer Program
>   Policies. Remember that additional enforcement could occur if there
>   are further policy issues with your apps. Submit your app. You can
>   reference this help center article for more details about the ratings
>   questionnaire.
>
> If you’ve reviewed the ads policy and feel this rejection may have
>   been in error, please reach out to our policy support team. One of my
>   colleagues will get back to you within 2 business days.
>
> Thanks for supporting Google Play!

Can you help me to find a solution for that ? 
And thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer helps other SO users.

If your app's Content rating does not allow you to display any adult / gambling or other sensitive content then the same is applicable to the ads that are displayed in your apps.

Using Admob [blocking controls](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3150953), you can control the types of ads that are displayed in your application to the end user

For more read [Avoid getting rejected on Google Play due to inappropriate ads in Admob](https://publishingfirstandroidapp.blogspot.com/2017/10/avoid-getting-rejected-on-google-play.html)

Comment: The blog post was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have declared your app to be for all age groups but have configured your ads to include those with adult content.

Comment: no one usually configures ads to include adult content, seems they work like this by default

Answer (score -1):

If your app does not contain any adult or sensitive content, try to re submit the app. This happened with me several times and my app did not contain any sensitive content. After resubmit, app was approved.

Comment: It's not about app's content, it's about ads' content. Can you read carefully?